# Haskell gsl-random - how to specify RNGType?

Tags: haskell, random, gsl

I'm trying to get the GSL bindings to distribution samplers working in haskell using gsl-random. I know there's random-fu as a higher-level option, but I'm finding random-fu is too slow for my purposes.

Say I want to sample from a beta distribution. The type specification based on the Hackage documentation is:

```
   getBeta :: RNG -> Double -> Double -> IO Double
```

I need an RNG object, this comes from the MkRNG

```
   newRNG :: RNGType -> IO RNG
```

How do I specify an RNGType?

```
λ> :i RNGType
newtype RNGType
  = gsl-random-0.5.0:GSL.Random.Gen.Internal.MkRNGType (GHC.Ptr.Ptr
                                                          ())
    -- Defined in ‘gsl-random-0.5.0:GSL.Random.Gen.Internal’
```

This is where I'm stuck. I don't understand how to instantiate an RNGType object based on this.

Comment: Have you tried `GSL.Random.Gen.mt19937` or `GSL.Random.Gen.rngType`?  Both of these functions return a `RNGType`.

Comment: that works, if you post that as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the functions `mt19937` and `rngType` from the `GSL.Random.Gen` module to build a `RNGType`, since the implementation of `RNGType` is internal to this library.